# Is there a cleaner way to add an additional switch statement to this code?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char grade;

    cout << "What grade did you earn in Programming I ?" << endl;
    cin >> grade;

    switch (grade)  // This is where the switch statement begins
    {
                              
        case 'A': cout << "an A - excellent work !" << endl;
                  break;
        case 'B': cout << "you got a B - good job" << endl;
                  break;
        case 'C': cout << "earning a C is satisfactory" << endl;
                  break;
        case 'D': cout << "while D is passing, there is a problem" << endl;
                  break;
        case 'F': cout << "you failed - better luck next time" << endl;
                  break;
        default: cout << "You did not enter an A, B, C, D, or F" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm supposed to add a statement that will additionally print out "YOU PASSED!" if the user enters a D or higher grade. I know I can just do it manually:

```
case 'A': cout << "YOU PASSED!" << endl;
                  cout << "an A - excellent work !" << endl;
                  break;
case 'B': cout << "YOU PASSED!" << endl; 
                  cout << "you got a B - good job" << endl;
                  break;
```

(etc)

but I was curious if there was a way to get it done with a single statement at the top of the switch statement e.g.

```
case 'A' || 'B' || 'C' || 'D': cout << "YOU PASSED!" << endl;
```

or

```
case 'A': case: 'B':(etc): cout << "YOU PASSED!" << endl;
```

I know (from trying) those don't work.

Comment: A separate conditional check above the `switch`. `if (grade >= 'A' && grade <= 'D') std::cout << "YOU PASSED!\n";`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want help improving working code, you should post this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you do decide to do so, please delete the question here.

Comment: Thank you sweenish, I was trying to add the additional check within the existing switch statement instead of adding it above. '

Comment: The other choice is to add a bool passed to the code and either initialize it true but set false for D/F or initialize false and set true for A-B-C. Then below the switch, output more info.

Comment: Have the default case `return 0;` and then put the `cout << "YOU PASSED!" << endl;` after the `switch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must do it with just `switch` and nothing else, you could nest them to handle the `'A'`-`'D'` and `'F'` cases separately (at the expense of a redundant `grade` check).

```
switch (grade)
{
case 'A':
case 'B':
case 'C':
case 'D': cout << "YOU PASSED!" << endl;
          switch(grade)
          {
          case 'A': cout << "an A - excellent work !" << endl;
              break;
          case 'B': cout << "you got a B - good job" << endl;
              break;
          case 'C': cout << "earning a C is satisfactory" << endl;
              break;
          case 'D': cout << "while D is passing, there is a problem" << endl;
              break;
          }
          break;
case 'F': cout << "you failed - better luck next time" << endl;
          break;
default:  cout << "You did not enter an A, B, C, D, or F" << endl;
          break;
}
```

The more economical way to write it would be to catch the invalid values upfront, then use the `grade` letter to index into an array of messages.

```
const char *message[] =
{
    "an A - excellent work !",
    "you got a B - good job",
    "earning a C is satisfactory",
    "while D is passing, there is a problem",
    "You did not enter an A, B, C, D, or F",
    "you failed - better luck next time"
};
if(grade < 'A' || grade > 'F')
    grade = 'E';
else if(grade <= 'D')
    cout << "YOU PASSED!" << endl;
cout << message[grade - 'A'] << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you line up cases with no code inside them and without any breaks, then the one after that group of code-less case statements will execute its code if its argument, or any of the previous arguments pass.

Note: the group of cases can have code inside, so if they do, think of it as the code carrying over to the next case with a break statement, but the code inside the break-less cases will only run if its or any of the previous cases' arguments are true. Also sorry for my hard to read text blocks.